# How to enforce https for java Play! app on Heroku?

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, playframework

I have a Java Play! app on Heroku that serves as a RESTful API.  I would like to enforce HTTP over TLS for all client connections.  What is the best practice for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest code is to **intercept the request** in `Global.java`

```
@Override
public Action onRequest(final Http.Request request, Method actionMethod) {

   //contains http or https
   String header=request.getHeader("x-forwarded-proto");

   if(header != null && header.equals("http")){

       return new Action.Simple() {
           @Override
           public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
               return F.Promise.pure(redirect("https://" + request.host() + request.path()));
           }
       };


   }
}
```

**Or with action composition** (useful to choose your "sensible" webservices)

In a new `ForceHttps.java` :

```
package actions;

import play.Play;
import play.libs.F;
import play.mvc.*;

public class ForceHttps extends Action<Controller> {

   // heroku header
   private static final String SSL_HEADER = "x-forwarded-proto";

   @Override
   public F.Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {

       if (Play.isProd() && !isHttpsRequest( ctx.request() )) {
           return F.Promise.promise(() -> redirect("https://" + ctx.request().host() + ctx.request().uri()) );
       }

       // let request proceed
       return this.delegate.call(ctx);
    }

    private static boolean isHttpsRequest(Http.Request request) {
       // heroku passes header on
       return request.getHeader(SSL_HEADER) != null && request.getHeader(SSL_HEADER).contains("https");
    }

}
```

In your `Application.java` (or before any class/method):

```
@With(ForceHttps.class)
public class Application extends Controller {
```

Comment: Thank you Julien for the help on Play!.  It turns out Heroku already supports HTTPS out of the box: "All default appname.herokuapp.com domains are SSL-enabled already and can be accessed simply by using https, e.g., https://appname.herokuapp.com."

Comment: Indeed if you setup the SSL addon, you can access your httpS://myapp.herokuapp.com, but does not mean that users will use it. If you want your website to be secure, to preserve credentials security or worse, credit card numbers, you need to force httpS